# How to avoid permission denied with caching files in Django?

Tags: django, caching, django-settings

I keep getting this issue from my django website, every time I have to go the path to remove the root access for all files and give access to the current user with `chown user_name:user_group *`, and it works. But after the website generating some new cached files, the problem gets back.

```
Internal Server Error: /

PermissionError at /
[Errno 13] Permission denied:'/var/tmp/project_cache/a92ccb8f0f5dc3d17dbaae74ac7.djcache'
```

I use django cache based on files. Here is my settings

```
CACHES = {
'default': {
    'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
    'LOCATION': '/var/tmp/project_cache',
    'TIMEOUT': 60 * 15,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'MAX_ENTRIES': 1000
    }
}
}
```

Do I need to never user cache with files?

Comment: You need to change ownership to the process user of your django process. Not the current user. Are you using uwsgi to run django or something else?

Comment: Yes I am using wsgi. I change the owner everytime I get the error

Comment: If you've set a `uid` and `gid` option in your uwsgi config file, you need to change ownership to those values. `uid` = user id and `gid` = group id.

Answer (score 1):

`/tmp/` and `/var/tmp/` are writable by all users.

I ask Django to create a folder for every single user so that I won't be bothered by `[Errno 13] Permission denied`.

```
import os
from pwd import getpwuid

__USERNAME = getpwuid(os.getuid()).pw_name

CACHES = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
        'LOCATION': f'/tmp/{__USERNAME}-django/',
    },
}
```

For example, `/tmp/ubuntu-django/` and `/tmp/www-data-django/` will be created respectively.